# E-mails not arriving - Rails, Heroku, Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to set up a contact form in rails, using a mailer and sendgrid . I'm running the app on Heroku.

I think that the Development and Production config files are ok,because i'm using Devise for authentication and its emails are being sent and received without any issue. So the problem is related to the mailer i've created.

The terminal shows that the e-mails are being triggered in development, and in production the heroku logs tell me that they are being sent. Everything looks ok, but the e-mails aren't arriving.

Thanks for any feedback.

This is the code:

*free_trial_form*

```
<%= form_tag("/public_pages/contato_free_trial", :id => 'free_trail_form') do %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :nome,nil, placeholder:"Seu nome", class: "form-control", id:"free_trail_form_nome_field" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= email_field_tag :email,nil, placeholder:"Seu e-mail", class: "form-control", id:"free_trail_form_email_field" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_area_tag :conteudo,nil, placeholder:"Veja na prática como é o nosso ensino. Digite aqui os horários mais confortáveis para você!", class: "form-control",id:"free_trail_form_text_area" %>
        </div>

        <div class="free_trail_form_area_btns">
            <%= button_tag(type:"submit", id: "free_trail_form_btn", class:"btn btn-danger",:onclick => "alert('Mensagem enviada. Obrigado!');") do %>
                        <span id="free_trail_form_btn_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
                        MARCAR AULA GRATUITA
            <% end %>
            <%=link_to(escola_path,id:"free_trail_form_escola_link") do %>

                <button id="free_trail_form_escola_link_btn" class="btn btn-primary">
                    OU SAIBA MAIS AGORA <span id="free_trail_form_escola_link_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                </button>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

*public_pages_controller/contato_free_trial*

```
def contato_free_trial
  @nome = params[:nome]
  @email = params[:email]
  @conteudo = params[:conteudo]
  PublicPagesMailer.free_trial_email(@nome,@email,@conteudo).deliver_now
  redirect_to(:back)
end
```

*public_pages_mailer*

```
class PublicPagesMailer < ApplicationMailer

def free_trial_email(nome,email,conteudo)
    @nome = nome
    @email = email
    @conteudo = conteudo
    mail(from: @email, to: 'contatoingleshi@gmail.com', subject: "Contato de Prospecto")
end
```

*Production config file*

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
 :port => '587',
 :authentication => :plain,
 :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
 :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
 :domain => 'heroku.com',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
config.cache_classes = true

config.eager_load = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true

config.log_level = :debug

config.i18n.fallbacks = true

config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that the email is correct in production environment.

Add this above to your code in your Production config file, you just have the first line but not the second one. Move the first one above and add the other code too.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "http://yourdomain/"}

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I can suggest, use "pry-rails" and "pry-navigation". In the methods that sends the email, you will put something like `binding.pry` and then in your console, you will see every step.

You can raise the errors of your mailer too. In your production environment check if you have something like this: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` and change to true.

Comment: No, i've tried what you suggested but without success so far. I truly don't know what to do. Everything seems ok but no email ever arrives

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output of you heroku logs?

Btw, check the heroku credentials set up for Sendgrid. In your heroku panel I think is on: “Settings” and then click “Reveal config vars”.

Just to be sure you have the correct credentials.